# group sql query output by date

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I've got a two tables I'm using to generate a report.

How would I get `x` axis on the report to show the results by say every month or two months?

I've tried this but by adding group by `inputdate` as well but it splits up all the emotions and counts.

```
SELECT ConceptName,COUNT(distinct blogId) As Tot
FROM conceptTable ct
JOIN blog on content LIKE '%'+ct.conceptName+'%'
GROUP BY conceptName
```

so at the moment it looks like this: [image]

instead I would like it to list `inputdate` on axis for every couple of months and the total times that conceptemotion showed up for that month.

Comment: stefan, you'll have to eliminate redundant grouping names from the client side. SQL Server can't eliminate cry from the cry/april combination just because it existed in the cry/march combination.

Comment: What's wrong with "Group By MONTH(inputdate)" ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably after something like

```
select ConceptName,cast(datepart(year, inputdate) as varchar) + '/' +
     cast(datepart(month, inputdate) as varchar) as RptMonth, COUNT(*) as
     Tot  
from conceptTable ct join blog on content like
     '%'+ct.conceptName+'%'  
group by conceptName, cast(datepart(year,
     inputdate) as varchar) + '/' + cast(datepart(month, inputdate) as
     varchar)
```

But you probably also need a left join to your emotions lookup table in there, so it will still show emotions if none exist for that month.